# Why do we use such a redundant language (English) for network communication?

Tags: encryption

I have heard throughout the internet that English is incredibly redundant. So why do we turn English messages in to a cipher which is then, from my understanding more vulnerable to letter frequency analysis (LFA). I think it would be more vulnerable to LFA because someone trying to decrypt the message would only need to get a certain percentage of the letters correct. Why not use something where the hacker would require a much higher percentage of matches to letters? Or am I speaking from ancient times and is LFA not so much of a problem with the more recent ciphers?

edit: Would it make more sense to use a much less redundant language, perhaps a custom language specifically for network communication where the source and destination nodes have translation software?

Thanks :)

Comment: You mean like [Navajo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_talker#Navajo_code_talkers)? Sure. If you and anyone you'd like to communicate with understand it...

Comment: This question comes from an incorrect viewpoint. You are talking as if the encryption algoritm has a preference for English (or any natural language for that matter). It does not, *we* do. So we compress English. To put it another way: your question text "we use English for network communications" is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

We don't use English for "network communication," we use network protocols. The things people say in natural language are usually much less interesting than the things computers say to each other.

LFA depends on the definition of a "letter." In English and ASCII (or more likely UTF-8) encoding, this corresponds to one byte. To do this kind of analysis, then, you need a single-byte cipher like XOR or a Caesar cipher. You can do similar things with a Vigenère cipher, with a little more work. These are not in common use, though: we usually use block ciphers or stream ciphers.

Block ciphers in Electronic Code Book (ECB) mode are subject to block frequency analysis, which is not as foolproof, but still is a valid attack. At larger scales, this is what is behind the "seeing the penguin" demo.

If any of this is interesting to you, I **highly** recommend you try [Matasano's Crypto Challenges](http://cryptopals.com/), which will take you through practical implementation of real crypto attacks, from frequency analysis on XOR ciphers to padding oracle and repeated-nonce attacks.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't entirely understand the answer, however, I will be spending some time reading about what you have mentioned. Seems to me from yours and other answers, it is completely a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

Very often we don't use straight English. We do run compression algorithms on the data. If you look at the [OpenPGP documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) it suggest compressing messages before encrypting them.

Compression algorithms remove the redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the question which you ask in the title is not complete. In your post you ask why we use English if we can use letter frequencies to decipher codes (encrypted text).

The reason is because we, humans, can understand it more easily and because it's not a huge issue. Protocols designed for speed are binary to avoid overhead (e.g. SPDY), but when HTTP was designed it was much more convenient to have a text-based protocol.

Sure we can make tools that read the traffic for us and, most of the time, we do. But sometimes the trade-off between extra size and increased readability makes (made?) sense. The fact that you can crack it when you encrypt it using an insecure cipher is not an issue with the protocol, it's an issue in the encryption cipher.

Besides, does it really prevent cracking the cipher if the encryption algorithm is so broken? I don't think so. Most webpages will contain common words or elements, you don't need a text-based network protocol for that.

Edit: Read your question a little more carefully and saw this:

> is LFA not so much of a problem with the more recent ciphers?

No, it's not. LFA is only an issue with encryption ciphers that are insecure by design. Ciphers like AES, RSA, DES, Twofish, Camellia, and basically everything else that we use nowadays, is secure. Just don't try to invent your own encryption, go with the standards and it'll be fine.